# What should be the appropriate choice of prior for a dummy variable in a Bayesian Linear regression?

Tags: bayesian, prior

I have a dataset where the dependent variable is Sales. The independent variables are Media Spends 1, Media Spends 2 and Covid dummy. I am trying to build a Bayesian Linear Regression model. The covid dummy is a dummy variable which has 0 and 1 as the values. For the coefficients of Media Spends 1 and 2, I have specified the prior distribution to Half Normal distribution. What should be the appropriate choice of prior for the coefficient of the covid dummy variable?

Comment: This is very subject matter knowledge-dependent.  This may only help slightly but when using normal priors in cases where we think the most likely value of $\beta=0$ I like to solve for $\sigma$ such that the prior probability that $\beta > c$ is $a$ for suitable $c$ and $a$.